# Camera in a CardScrollView

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Does anyone have some code samples that implements a Camera in a CardScrollView/CardScrollAdapter? I'm basically looking to create an adapter of cards with placeholders then, tap on a card, take a photo, then swipe to move to next card, and take another photo for that placeholder card and so on.

Answer (score 1):

checkout the open quartz project, it has implementations for camera capture and video render class.

https://github.com/jaredsburrows/OpenQuartz/blob/master/example-apps/OG_CameraApp/src/com/openquartz/camera/CameraView.java

here is an adaption of the cardscrolladapter https://github.com/w9jds/CardScrollView-Example

You probably want to create a tap event that throws a camera intent, and then passes the path where the picture was stored back into the cardscrolladapter card list. Then create a card and set the image as the background of the card.

The card scroll effect should look like a camera roll of pictures you just took.

Also @w9jds has a Gallery4Glass project that sounds similar. https://github.com/w9jds/Gallery4Glass